# ROS Answers SE migration: catkin & uses

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What exactly is **catkin**? How is it used in ROS? What are its different types?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262421/catkin-&-uses/) by [akhilkathi](https://answers.ros.org/users/30211/akhilkathi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-24**:
This reads like a homework assignment.

What have you found yourself? There's quite some documentation on catkin available, including the design goals and implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Read:

[Catkin](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin)

[Catkin - Conceptual Overview](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/conceptual_overview)

---

Originally posted by [chwimmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/21005/chwimmer/) with karma: 436 on 2017-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1